# There is any way to create a class with the same behavior as dynamic or ExpandoObject?

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

I want to create a class with fixed properties and the capability to extend them as **dynamic** or **ExpandoObject** can.
e.g:

```
public class DynamicInstance : DynamicObject
{
    public string FixedTestProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
DynamicInstance myCustomObj = new DynamicInstance();

myCustomObj.FixedTestProperty = "FixedTestValue";
myCustomObj.DynamicCreatedTestProperty = "Custom dynamic property value";
```

Finally if I serialize that class with json.net or something else output something like that:

```
{
   FixedTestProperty: 'FixedTestValue',
   DynamicCreatedTestProperty: 'Custom dynamic property value'
}
```

Comment: So, what did you try? Inheriting from `DynamicObject` is indeed the way to go.

Comment: You can use [this](https://github.com/RickStrahl/Expando) library. See this [blog post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/feb/08/creating-a-dynamic-extensible-c-expando-object) for more info.

Comment: @s.m. yes I think so, but with this implementation I'm missing intellisense of fixed properties. Maybe there is any way to avoid that. Because if I don't have intellisense for that properties I think there is no reason to create my own object instead of create a **dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject()**.

Comment: @Saravana thanks I saw that but posted on a blog. I will take a look on this repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inherit `DynamicObject` and override the `TryGetMember` and `TrySetMember` methods. Here is a class which has one property named `One`. However, you can add more to it dynamically.

```
public class ExpandOrNot : DynamicObject
{
    public string One { get; set; }

    // The inner dictionary.
    Dictionary<string, object> dictionary
        = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    // This property returns the number of elements
    // in the inner dictionary.
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return dictionary.Count;
        }
    }

    // If you try to get a value of a property 
    // not defined in the class, this method is called.
    public override bool TryGetMember(
        GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        // Converting the property name to lowercase
        // so that property names become case-insensitive.
        string name = binder.Name.ToLower();

        // If the property name is found in a dictionary,
        // set the result parameter to the property value and return true.
        // Otherwise, return false.
        return dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out result);
    }

    // If you try to set a value of a property that is
    // not defined in the class, this method is called.
    public override bool TrySetMember(
        SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        // Converting the property name to lowercase
        // so that property names become case-insensitive.
        dictionary[binder.Name.ToLower()] = value;

        // You can always add a value to a dictionary,
        // so this method always returns true.
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
dynamic exp = new ExpandOrNot { One = "1" };
exp.Two = "2";
```

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx).

[<== Fiddle Me ==>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iRsoZr)

Comment: Oh ok I understand, but there is no way to get fixed properties on intelisense when I type **exp.**

Comment: If the reference is of type `dynamic` then no you will not get any intellisence. But if you cast to `ExpandoOrNot` then you will get intellisence for the members of that.

Comment: That's true! thanks. Just an other thing. Do you know why **JObject.FromObject(exp)** returns an empty JObject?

Answer (score -1):

This is possible using TrySetMember on DynamicObject.

The example at the bottom of this shows how to do it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trysetmember(v=vs.110).aspx